# Using two different versions of Stata

Tags: stata

I am working in two locations, in one I am using Stata 13 and in the other Stata 14.

Can I build a do-file that works in both versions even if some specific command has changed?

For instance, the following code will not work using Stata 13

```
sysuse auto, clear
ci means mpg price, level(90)
```

but this one works

```
sysuse auto, clear
ci mpg price, level(90)
```

Uising Stata 14, it will be the opposite.

I thought about adding `capture` but nothing happens in Stata 13 or Stata 14.

```
. sysuse auto, clear
(1978 Automobile Data)

. capture ci means mpg price, level(90)

. capture ci mpg price, level(90)
```

---

**Update:** Adding `noisily` after `capture` didn't help unfortunately. Here is an example with Stata 14 that works

```
 . sysuse auto, clear
(1978 Automobile Data)

. capture noisily ci mpg price, level(90)
you must specify one of means, proportions, or variances following ci

. capture noisily ci means mpg price, level(90)

    Variable |        Obs        Mean    Std. Err.       [90% Conf. Interval]
-------------+---------------------------------------------------------------
         mpg |         74     21.2973    .6725511        20.17683    22.41776
       price |         74    6165.257    342.8719        5594.033     6736.48

. gen lb=r(lb) 

. su lb

    Variable |        Obs        Mean    Std. Dev.       Min        Max
-------------+---------------------------------------------------------
          lb |         74    5594.033           0   5594.033   5594.033
```

But this one does not work when you invert two lines of code (with Stata 14):

```
   . sysuse auto, clear
    (1978 Automobile Data)

    . capture noisily ci means mpg price, level(90)

        Variable |        Obs        Mean    Std. Err.       [90% Conf. Interval]
    -------------+---------------------------------------------------------------
             mpg |         74     21.2973    .6725511        20.17683    22.41776
           price |         74    6165.257    342.8719        5594.033     6736.48

    . capture noisily ci mpg price, level(90)
    you must specify one of means, proportions, or variances following ci

* The program didn't stop but:

    . gen lb=r(lb) 
    (74 missing values generated)

    . su lb

        Variable |        Obs        Mean    Std. Dev.       Min        Max
    -------------+---------------------------------------------------------
              lb |          0
```

Finally, note that the first code that works correctly with Stata 14 doesn't work with Stata 13

```
. sysuse auto, clear
(1978 Automobile Data)

. capture noisily ci mpg price, level(90)

    Variable |        Obs        Mean    Std. Err.       [90% Conf. Interval]
-------------+---------------------------------------------------------------
         mpg |         74     21.2973    .6725511        20.17683    22.41776
       price |         74    6165.257    342.8719        5594.033     6736.48

. capture noisily ci means mpg price, level(90)
variable means not found

. gen lb=r(lb) 
(74 missing values generated)

. su lb

    Variable |       Obs        Mean    Std. Dev.       Min        Max
-------------+--------------------------------------------------------
          lb |         0
```

Comment: `version 13:  ci mpg price, level(90)` should work in this case in both 13 and 14, although neither version is to hand. The general question is a good one, but there isn't a simple generic answer beyond consider `version:`.

Comment: It works indeed. Thanks. Just for curiosity's sake: I am wondering why `capture` doesn't work here.

Comment: `capture` eats the displayed output as well as the error, not what you want. I just tried `sysuse auto` followed by `capture noisily ci means mpg price` and it worked fine in 15.1, so I don't know what to make of your last sentence. If you want more on that, you need to document "does not help".

Comment: I updated my post to see why adding `noisily` did not help much.

Comment: That's a different problem. Your second command failed, but before so doing the r-class results in memory were flushed. You shouldn't try the second command if the first command worked. You should use r-class results before the next r-class command you tried.

Comment: I surely missed something but one order will work with Stata 14 (the first code) but not with Stata 13 and vice versa. So the same code cannot be used for the 2 versions.

Comment: You're right, but I didn't say it could. That's one reason why the `version:` solution is better. I'll write an answer, but I can't test it on either 13 or 14 at the moment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you wish to use `capture` to catch an error, there is follow-through as well. Here you first try version 14 syntax, and **if and only if that fails** you try version 13 syntax.

```
sysuse auto, clear
capture noisily ci means mpg price, level(90)
if _rc ci mpg price, level(90)
gen lb = r(lb)
```

Here `if _rc` is a Stataish abbreviation for `if _rc > 0` which will happen if and only if a program fails. `_rc` of 0 means everything was legal (with minute qualifications). `_rc` is the return code.

I am not clear that putting a single value in a variable is a good idea, but let that be a different issue. Also, you asked for two confidence intervals, and only results for the first will remain in memory.

Comment: Thanks! The `gen lb=r(lb)` command was for the sake of illustration. I am sure it's not a good idea!